# Error "Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value" even after return in all places

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

I am new to Node.js and I am struggling with Promises even after reading the tutorials provided by other stackflow users. I have already spent a whole evening on this and I am looking for help. I get the following error " Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value". My code is below. What am I doing wrong? I also have a suspicion that I have to use await/async because it looks like my code is running through without waiting for the first get to complete.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var db = admin.firestore();

exports.declinedRequest = functions.firestore
.document('requests/{requestId}')
.onUpdate((change, context) => {
  const newValue = change.after.data();
  const status = newValue.status;
  const request = context.params.requestId;
  var registrationToken;
  var message;

  if(status=="created") {
    console.log('Checkpoint1 ',context.params.requestId);
    newValue.friends.forEach(doc => {
      console.log('Checkpoint 2: ', doc);

      var usersRef = db.collection('users');
      var query = usersRef.where('mobile', '==', doc).get()
        .then(snapshotFriend => {
          if (snapshotFriend.empty) {
            console.log('Checkpoint3.');
            return;
          }  

        snapshotFriend.forEach(mobile => {

        registrationToken = mobile.data().fcmToken;
        console.log('FCM token =>', registrationToken);
        if (!registrationToken) {
          console.log('No fcmToken available');
          return;
        }  
         message = {
          notification: {
            body: "Request still available from " + newValue.requesterName,
            sound: "default", 
            badge: 1
            },
          data: {
            requestId: `${request}`
          }
        };

        console.log('FCM token message created');

        }) 
      })
    })
  } else {
    return;
  }
 return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationToken, message)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log("Successfully sent message:", response)
     })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
     }) 

})
```

Comment: The main problem is that you're not returning a promise from the top level of your function when it enters the first `if` block.  Returns nested in callbacks and functions aren't returning from the top level.  Also, you never have any obligation to use async/await, as it's just a convenient syntax for the same thing you do with promises using `then`.

Comment: You might be helped by watching [this video series](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/) on Cloud Functions, and how to use promises in it.  It also helps to start with a simple function, then add complexity later.  Right now, what you have is rather complex for someone who is new to node.

Comment: Thank you, Doug. I have watch this video series, but have not come across any suggestions on how to fix it when the if is at the top level. I did one change based on your feedback (updated code above). However, now it looks like the return at the bottom is executing sooner than the code above. I am struggling to insert await before return. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below hope this will work.

```
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const Promise = require('bluebird');
    const _ = require('lodash');
    let db = admin.firestore();

    exports.declinedRequest = functions.firestore
    .document('requests/{requestId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
        const newValue = change.after.data();
        const status = newValue.status;
        const request = context.params.requestId;
        if (status == "created") {
            console.log('Checkpoint1 ', context.params.requestId);
            allPromises = [];
            newValue.friends.forEach(doc => {
                console.log('Checkpoint 2: ', doc);
                const usersRef = db.collection('users');
                // query for each document return promise.
                allPromises.push(queryForEachDocument(doc,request,usersRef));
            });
            return Promise.all(allPromises);
        } else {
            return Promise.reject / resolve('Whatever you want.');
        }
    })

    function queryForEachDocument(doc,request,usersRef) {
    let promiseInvoices = []
    let registrationToken;
    let message;
    return usersRef.where('mobile', '==', doc).get().then((snapshotFriend) => {
        if (_.isEmpty(snapshotFriend)) {
            console.log('Checkpoint3.');
            return Promise.reject(new Error('Your error'));
        }
        snapshotFriend.forEach(mobile => {
            registrationToken = mobile.data().fcmToken;
            console.log('FCM token =>', registrationToken);
            if (!registrationToken) {
                console.log('No fcmToken available for', newValue.requesterName);
                // Do anything you want to change here.
                return Promise.reject(new Error('No fcmToken available for',newValue.requesterName));
            }
            message = {
                notification: {
                    body: "Request still available from " + newValue.requesterName,
                    sound: "default",
                    badge: 1
                },
                data: {
                    requestId: request
                }
            };
            console.log('FCM token message created');
            // send invoice for each registrationToken
            promiseInvoices.push(sendInvoice(registrationToken, message))
        });
    }).then(() => {
        return Promise.all(promiseInvoices);
    })
    }
    function sendInvoice(registrationToken, message) {
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationToken, message)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("Successfully sent message:", response)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, Shubham, for correcting my code. It works well except I could not get it to deploy with  Promise.reject / resolve('Whatever you want.'). What does the / mean? I had to drop the reject and / to make it work. Do you know why?

Comment: You can either resove that thing or reject not the both its upto you what you want to do. So in case of success you can resove the thing and if you think there should be an error you can call reject, I am not able to find what the exact thing you want to do thats why i written  `return Promise.reject / resolve('Whatever you want.')` , You can write return **Promise.resolve('Whatever you want.')** or **return Promise.reject ('Whatever you want.');**